# Different behaviour of GenerationType.AUTO + @SequenceGenerator when migrated from Hibernate 3.6 to 5.1

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

In Hibernate 3.6 we had a working code on both MySql and Oracle:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "applicationEventLog", sequenceName = "S_APPLICATION_EVENT_LOG")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "applicationEventLog")
private Integer id;
```

On MySql using autoincrement, and on Oracle it was using the sequence stated with `sequenceName`. So it is sequence created on db by us, not a hibernate generated one.

After upgrading hibernate to 5.1, it is no longer using sequence stated in `@SequenceGenerator`, instead it is using `hibernate_sequence` and ids conflict with existing ones. If I change GenerationType to SEQUENCE:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "applicationEventLog")
```

it does use the stated sequence, but SEQUENCE is not applicable to MySql.

Is there a way to achieve the old behavior: to have `GenerationType.AUTO` but use the sequence with the name stated in `@SequenceGenerator`?

Comment: You can revert to the old behaviour by setting the property  hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings to false e.g. in Spring specify the following: <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>. This property is by default true in Hibernate 5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this by changing to hibernate's `@GenericGenerator` instead of `@SequenceGenerator`:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
@GenericGenerator(name = "applicationEventLog", strategy = "native", parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM, value = "S_APPLICATION_EVENT_LOG"),
})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "applicationEventLog")
private Integer id;
```

Answer (score 1):

`AUTO` means leave it up to the JPA provider to choose what type of generator it uses. `SEQUENCE` forces it to use a `SEQUENCE`. As per the JPA spec. If you want one specific generator then you should SPECIFY IT, rather than rely on the JPA provider to just happen across the same one as you really wanted

Comment: I cannot use specific strategy, when different db engines use different strategies. `AUTO` is using autoincrement on mysql, and sequence on oracle, and that is ok, i just need a way to tell it to use the stated sequence. Like it used to do in Hibernate 3.

Comment: Which is why there is orm.xml so you can have one for each datastore .. so then the MySQL orm.xml would use IDENTITY, and the Oracle orm.xml would use SEQUENCE etc. Using some JPA vendors hardcoded internal feature is basically non-portable; the only truly portable way is to use the orm.xml route.